# Unable to execute java program from jsp using Runtime.getRuntime().exec

Tags: java, jsp, runtime.exec

I am trying to run a jar file through jsp. I use the command `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar file.jar");` I get the error `Unable to access jarfile file.jar` when I print the error stream.

I tried running with the classpath set to the current directory as `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -cp . -jar file.jar");` but still get the same error. I also tried giving the entire path to the jar file. When I do this, the jsp file hangs after execuing the exec statement.

This is the line I use in windows:

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar C:\\Users\\Jeff\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\WebApplication1\\file.jar");
```

I use the streamgobbler thing given in [the article](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4) but still have the same problem (hangs). Can someone help?

Comment: Why do you need to run jar file from a jsp?

Comment: Instead of doing Runtime.exec, can't you include the jar file in your web application and call the appropriate class/function directly?

Answer (score 3):

It will never work. Otherwise it would be security breach. Imagine that you could run any executable from web browser... You should put your classes on server, make them accessible to your jsp and then run some method from jsp.

Comment: agreed.. client's jar/executable can not be accessible through `JSP`.. not sure about `Java Applet`

Comment: JSP is executed on a server, not on a client. JSP do not have access to client's executables.

Comment: @Yatskevitch, of course that the corresponding servlet page executes on server that is not what was said.

Comment: the answer is incorrect. most of the time it should work, it wont work only if security manager is present... and that's not very often

Comment: the jar file is on the server. I have a html form that's displayed in the client side. When a submit button is clicked, the jsp is executed on the server and as a first step I want the jar to be executed on the server machine(currently localhost) and as a next step, execute the jar on a remote machine using ssh.

Comment: @user1151450 still fail to understand why do you need to do it by running executable (java.exe) from JSP and not by running the code in your jar directly?

Comment: @bestsss, when was the last time you saw a commercial web server that ran with securityManger disabled?

Comment: @aviad, honestly? today. controlling the process by OS restrictions is plenty.

Comment: @bestsss well, I guess you have your reasons for doing that. however,  based on my experience, disabling securityManager in production environment is not a good idea and is not something that IT would be happy to do.

Answer (score 1):

Though it's better to add a jar to `WEB-INF/lib` and execute needed functionality using method call or at least move scriptlet code to a servlet, it's **perfectly legal** to use any functionality provided by Java in JSP scriptlets.

**test.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <%
    try {
      Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
      Process exec = runtime.exec(new String[]{"java", "-cp", "/home/test/test.jar", "Main"});
      int i = exec.waitFor();
      System.out.println(i);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  %>
  hi
  </body>
</html>
```

`test.jar` contains the following class:

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println('hello');
  }

}
```

This example runs fine. JSP prints `0` in a server output stream which means that no error has happened.

While you're developing webapp locally your machine is a server and a client at the same time. This thing can confuse you, so you have to *understand* that the code from jar file you are trying to run will be executed on a _server.

In your case the problem is caused by the code in jar file itself. Try to create a simple class and see if it works.