# How to run sudo poweroff in java

Tags: java, jsp, sudo, runtime.exec, power-off

I am a jsp developer. I need to shut down my slow, unresponsive, laggy, (you get the point) development ubuntu "server" sometimes, when its keyboard stops responding to input. I already have tomcat configured properly, and even when my keyboard stops responding, I can use it as a server (accessing webpages served by tomcat). My idea is to make a jsp page that calls `sudo poweroff`. But I have no idea how to do that. I have tried

```
Runtime.getRuntime.exec("sudo poweroff");
```

but it does not work for me. I have already edited the sudoers file to allow the tomcat user to perform this action without requiring a password. How can I make this happen?

Comment: This might help you for Runtime.exec(): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877236/unable-to-execute-java-program-from-jsp-using-runtime-getruntime-exec . If you need to sudo, you can write a C program that's setuid root that calls poweroff.

Comment: You can't do this. It's impossible

Comment: This is a terrible idea, but you want `sudo /sbin/shutdown -h now`. It would probably be a better idea to install openssh-server and use a remote ssh to shut it down.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch This is only my development server. It ***obviously*** would not be used in production. But can I do `sudo /shin/poweroff`? Just wondering....

Comment: Try it, and see for yourself. And if the answer isn't **yes**, keep ***trying***.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Oh, and I tried ssh, but I had a lot of connection issues. It would only accept connections from my iPad for some reason, not from PuTTY on my computer. But that's another issue

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters & to separate the parts of the command.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch If you make your original comment an answer, I will select it.

Answer (score 2):

If the user running tomcat has sudo perms (w/o a password), it should be doable - but the call should be something like this:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"sudo", "poweroff"});`

The command and parameters can't all be passed in one big string.

Check out the docs for more info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])

PS: This is probably a bad idea. :)

Comment: The java docs also have [this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) so your answer is incorrect, at least according to the reasoning you gave

Comment: Did you try it? The method you refer to is for a command without parameters.