# Run Python script from java code

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, jsp, servlets

This is the first time I am trying python in java.
I am trying to execute python script from my code as follows.

```
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\demo\\filename.py");
```

But I am getting following exception

"Cannot run program "python": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified"

I have installed python.
I am not sure why the file is not found.
I tried to follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097491/call-and-receive-output-from-python-script-in-java) but it did not solve my issue.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1**

I tried the sample code given by "Viacheslav Vedenin", it worked when I executed my java(servlet) program. But when I ran the same function from JSP button click event, it did not work. 
It gave me following error

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: You can add to the path Enviroment Variable the path of python soo thenyou will be able to execute a python command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use full path to python, for example

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Python\\python.exe  
          C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\demo\\filename.py");
```

Comment: I tried above sample and it worked when I ran my java program.
But when I ran the same function from JSP button click event, it did not work.
It gave me following error

 java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: You may have problem if you try to run program from JSP, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877236/unable-to-execute-java-program-from-jsp-using-runtime-getruntime-exec , https://coderanch.com/t/282987/java/Runtime-getRuntime-exec-working-JSP